# Flutter Stepper focus view on header of stepper on step change

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I have `Stepper` where every `Step` is dynamically build after opening. Steps are various, once they height is less than 1/2 of screen height, another time Step have 2x of screen height. As I said previously, widgets inside steppers are build automatically using `FutureBuilder`s widgets, so `Stepper` could change his height realtime.

I try do it using `FocusNode` and force focus on first element of each `Step`, but my solution is not working every time.
How to force move of screen scroll to beginning of current opened `Step`? It means that title of current `Step` should be just below `Scaffold`s `AppBar`.

Of course my widget stack looks like this:

```
Scaffold
ScrollView
Stepper
Step (with header and buttons)
step content: Column (with form widgets and a lot of Text widgets)
```